# Attribute Error while trying to select an option using pywinauto in python

Tags: python, attributeerror, pywinauto

I'm trying to select an option(2)(i.e., "start with select and end with last in group" from the popped box while double-clicking "Button2".
 But, what I'm getting is this...

```
 File "C:\XXXX\XXX XX\Resources\XXXXX XXX XXX\pywinAuto_test.py", line 12, in <module>
    application.Options.keyboard.SendKeys('{DOWN 3}')
AttributeError: 'ButtonWrapper' object has no attribute 'keyboard
```

Answer (score 1):

It's wrong usage of module `keyboard`. This code is correct:

```
application.Options.type_keys('{DOWN 3}')
```

If bring "Options" to focus is not necessary, there are 2 options:

```
application.Options.type_keys('{DOWN 3}', set_foreground=False)

# or direct usage of module "keyboard"
keyboard.SendKeys('{DOWN 3}')
```